# react native SectionList component scrolling does not work if I use renderSectionHeader props before renderItem

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new to React Native and found this strange behaviour that `react native` `SectionList` component scrolling does not work if I use `renderSectionHeader` props before `renderItem`

**Vertical scrolling Not Working**

```
<SectionList
      sections={DATA}
      renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => (
        <View style={styles.item}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>{section.title}</Text>
        </View>
      )}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <Text style={styles.text}>{item}</Text>
      )}
      
    />
```

**Vertical scrolling Working**

```
<SectionList
      sections={DATA}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <Text style={styles.text}>{item}</Text>
      )}
      renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => (
        <View style={styles.item}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>{section.title}</Text>
        </View>
      )}
    />
```

Is this a bug as header is displayed first and later its children

Answer (score 0):

I've compared your example with the one listed on the [React Native docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist). The difference is having the `keyExtractor` prop.

By taking out this `keyExtractor` prop, the scrolling behaviour of the component doesn't function at all, irregardless of the positioning of the `renderSectionHeader` and `renderItem` props.

Can you try adding the `keyExtractor` prop below and see if both prop arrangements affect the scrolling behaviour?

```
keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have remove {flex: 1} from contentContainerStyle attribute on SectionList, and now scrolling is work perfect.